# How to make Simultaneous Output to my two bluetooth headphones using Pipewire?

Tags: linux, audio, pipewire

I have two Bluetooth headphones, I want to create a virtual sink such that when selected, both of my headphones play Audio simultaneously. I am using pipewire.

I followed [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices), to create a virtual sink, but they have not mentioned how to link the two Bluetooth headphones. I tried some combinations with pw-link, but it is not trivial.

Please Give an example to do the same.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

HM

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution would be to use pipewire's Jack server and simply adjust the node graph. You could check out:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#JACK_clients

An example command would be: `pw-jack qjackctl`. Then click the "Graph" button, and finally drag a connection between the source of your audio and your two headphones' sinks.